# What should i use for better performance, nine-patch or drawable xml resource?

Tags: android, performance, nine-patch, android-drawable, xml-drawable

What is the best way to set background for some view? For example 2 variants of backround:

1. background with gradient, rounded corners and border
2. background with just one color and rounded corners

So which of variants would be better, nine-patch or drawable xml resource?

Comment: I dont't know! :) But since the standard android themes use 9patch alot, i would asume that doing so can't be too wrong.

Comment: I meen if i need just one color background, maybe xml resourse would be faster? At least xml file would be smaller size

Comment: if you only need one color, set background with it . no need image resource ,no need xml config

Comment: but, what if i need rounded corners?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess is, `NinePatch` would be slightly faster in most cases. Here's what I found.

`GradientDrawable` (the one used for rects in xml) uses [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#249) to call through to `Canvas` which in turn uses native call leading to [`SkCanvas`](http://skia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/core/SkCanvas.cpp), [`SkDraw`](http://skia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/core/SkDraw.cpp) and eventually [`SkScan`](http://skia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/core/SkScan.cpp) and [`SkBlitter`](http://skia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/core/SkBlitter.cpp).

On the other hand, [`NinePatch`'s draw() has almost zero Java code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/graphics/NinePatch.java#103) before the native [call to `NinePatch.cpp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/NinePatch.cpp) which [shortly calls `NinePatchImpl.cpp` -- `NinePatch_draw()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/NinePatchImpl.cpp) --- and that's where the magic is. The code there iterates over the marked regions and after a number of subsequent calls draws stuff using roughly the same logic in `SkDraw` (only `drawRect()` instead of `drawPath()`) but in the end it's the same `SkScan` and `SkBlitter` that do the work.

All that code is pretty hard to wrap my head around instantly, but what did catch my eye is that `GradientDrawable` makes two calls to the whole native stack if it has both background and stroke ([look here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#318)), while in any scenario a `NinePatch` only makes one.

So, without actually measuring times for both approaches I get a feeling in most cases `NinePatch` wins the race: if we *[awfully]* roughly assume that native call stacks for `drawRect()` and `drawPath()` use pretty much the same logic and *[another awful simplification]* the parameter sets that get passed around there and are created by `NinePatch` and `GradientDrawable` don't affect complexity of the methods that much, then `NinePatch` turns out to be roughly 2 times faster than `GradientDrawable` with filling and outline. Well, provided you use a regular, 9-section 9-Patch (i.e. don't shred you 9-Patch by an awful lot of markers, making the iteration over the pieces overly effort-expensive).

*Anyone who'll stumble upon this and knows more on the subject (and/or better at estimating complexity of native code), please, correct me if I'm wrong.*

*PS yeah, I know this is not much of a straight answer*

Comment: Great job, thanks for your answer. It's almost what i wanted to hear. You showed to me a good example to look deeper in source :)

Comment: Actually, I'm editing the answer right now, turns out I overlooked some stuff, so I'm removing some of the argumentation :) But afaik the outcome is the same - `NinePatches` win.

Comment: +1. In simplest words : ready made pixel data versus procedurally generated one with extra CPU cycles. This is true in general computer graphics as well.