# Button with Nine-patch or Style?

Tags: android, xml, nine-patch

I'm making an app with custom buttons, but I want to know is it better to use the nine-patch tool or define styles and colors in xml. My buttons change in height and width but they do not have images, just words, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link also. [What should i use for better performance, nine-patch or drawable xml resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073505/what-should-i-use-for-better-performance-nine-patch-or-drawable-xml-resource). Both approaches have is own merits. Select one option as per your situation

Answer (score 0):

no you don't need to use nine-patch just give the width,height,and text sizes in values folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a fairly simple shape, you might as well use a shape to create the background.

first create a `button_shape.xml`  file in drawable resource directory:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#505050"/>
    <corners 
        android:radius="7dp" />

    <padding 
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#505050"/>

</shape>
```

Now, assign it to the backround of you `Button`.

```
android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
```

You will need to change some of the color values to fit your needs